# angular ui router - each link in menu leads to different module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a menu with 5 tabs, each tab has ui-sref to its state.

each state is another module.

I have the main module which contains the nav , and 5 moduls for each page.

Each module has router of itself.

I tried to do something like this :

The main html page with menu:

```
 <div ng-app="app">
      <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="module1">Module1</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="module2">Module2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div data-ui-view></div>
  </div>
```

the main module:

```
 angular.module('app', [ 'app.module1', 'ui.router'])
.config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('module1', {
        url: "/module1",
        templateUrl: "Scripts/Partials/module1.html"
    })
    .state('module2', {
        url: "/module2",
        templateUrl: "Scripts/Partials/module2.html"
    });

};
```

in module1.html for example I did :

```
<div>
  <h2>Module 1</h2>
    <div ng-app="app.module1">
      <div data-ui-view></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the module of module1 looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.module1', [])
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('module1Default');
.config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('module1Default', {
        url: "/module1Default",
        templateUrl: "Scripts/Partials/module1Default.html"
    });
};
```

But it doesnt work! when I click on link of module1, I dont see even the header of this page.

What wrong here?

Comment: can u tell me why you have used two angular modules?

Comment: Only a single `ng-app` is needed - you shouldn't include it also in the view template. Not sure that this is the issue, but it wouldn't hurt to remove. Also, your `module1` module is a bit messed up, not to mention that you are including `app.module1` in the app

Comment: I use two moduls because each page in my application is a little application itself, with ui router for itself.I have 5 tabs with 5 little applictions so I prefer to seperate it into different moduls

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) ~ *"AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other"*

Comment: So I have to put all the applications in the same module? It doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can register states in any order and across modules. You can register children before the parent state exists. It will queue them up and once the parent state is registered then the child will be registered. Note: You still need to manage module dependencies.

```
angular.module('main', ['main.page1']).config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main', {...})
});

angular.module('main.page1', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main.page1', {...})
});
```